# Deadlock at update query only when more than two transaction at same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-update, deadlock

When writing some SQL Server update queries for interfacing a product database, I ran into a situation where everything is fine if two transactions with these updates are running at the same time - but when more than two transactions are trying to update the same table simultaneously, some of them were deadlocked.

I broke the problem down to a "UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED" constraint to the table definition. When I remove this constraint, all transactions will wait for their needed resources and finish without errors.

Here is my sample-code to reproduce the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[profiles]
(
    [ProfileID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [ProfileName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL, 
    [GroupFK] [int] NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Profile] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProfileID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY],
    -- !!! [UI_UniqueNameInGroup] seems problematic for me because i get deadlocks when executing more than two transactions at once !!!
    CONSTRAINT [UI_UniqueNameInGroup] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([GroupFK] ASC, [ProfileName] ASC)
                      WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                            IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                            ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO profiles (ProfileName) VALUES ('PROFILE_99')
INSERT INTO profiles (ProfileName) VALUES ('PROFILE_88')
INSERT INTO profiles (ProfileName) VALUES ('PROFILE_77')
INSERT INTO profiles (ProfileName) VALUES ('PROFILE_66')
```

These are samples of my transactions:

```
BEGIN TRAN  
     UPDATE profiles 
     SET ProfileName = 'NewProfile_99' 
     WHERE ProfileID = 4

     WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05.000'
COMMIT TRAN
```

```
BEGIN TRAN  
     UPDATE profiles 
     SET ProfileName = 'NewProfile_66' 
     WHERE ProfileID = 1

     WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05.000'
COMMIT TRAN
```

```
BEGIN TRAN  
     UPDATE profiles 
     SET ProfileName = 'NewProfile_88' 
     WHERE ProfileID = 3

     WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05.000'
COMMIT TRAN
```

```
BEGIN TRAN  
     UPDATE profiles 
     SET ProfileName = 'NewProfile_77' 
     WHERE ProfileID = 2

     WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05.000'
COMMIT TRAN
```

Here are my deadlock-graphs:

[deadlockgraph1.xdl](https://www.file-upload.net/download-14107197/deadlockgraph1.xdl.html)

[deadlockgraph2.xdl](https://www.file-upload.net/download-14107194/deadlockgraph2.xdl.html)

Please help me by explaining the problem to me - I don't get it why deadlocks only happen when executing more than two transactions simultaneously.

I'm also cool with just getting a working solution for this.

Is there a solution at my side (without changing the database scheme)?

Comment: The options define `ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF` when they both default to `ON`. Was that intentional?

Comment: Both options were originally set to ON - i switched them to OFF to test if something changes in my problem - my fault, that i did not revert that before posting the code. I changed it in the code of the original post

Comment: @Gerald Are you able to reproduce the issue when the index allows row/page locks? I am unable to, and changing these options might be the answer that you are looking for. With these options set to off, I can workaround the problem by explicitly locking the entire table using `WITH (TABLOCK)` during the update, but explicitly preventing more granular locks in the index only to have to explicitly lock the entire table seems pretty backwards.

Comment: @GarethD i'm not able to reproduce the problem on the demonstration code i posted anymore after allowing row/page locks. But i still have deadlock problem when i try this in production - so maybe i still have another issue, i have to analyze. so, for the demo code your suggestions solves my problem - ty

Comment: @All Please explain why the transactions (update queries) are not waiting for the ressources (lock on table/row) to become free when more then two of them are parallel? Why are they not simply wait?

Answer (score 1):

Change constraint [UI_UniqueNameInGroup] to allow only row locks:

```
CONSTRAINT [UI_UniqueNameInGroup] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([GroupFK] ASC, [ProfileName] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This causes a problem because if you deny page and row lock then you force SQL Server to use table lock but other session already put a table lock.

Comment: this works for my demo code! too bad, that i still get deadlock in production environment

Comment: Try one more thing. Change order of columns in constraint [UI_UniqueNameInGroup], this way:
CONSTRAINT [UI_UniqueNameInGroup] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([ProfileName] ASC, [GroupFK] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF
) ON [PRIMARY]